# How to make a pseudo-class underline swipe from bottom to top with CSS?

Tags: html, css, transition, underline

I'm a beginner at CSS for about a week.
And this is my first question on stack overflow.
Hope that I'm asking in the right way. I'm happy to receive any corrections.

#### The problem

I use pseudo-class to make an underline that grows thicker when hovered.
I want to have it swipe from bottom to top while it swipes from top to bottom.
How can I make it?

I did search for similar questions but end up with block elements (gradient etc).
Thanks a lot!

[Here is my code on CodePen.](https://codepen.io/minglelingo/pen/Exmyyqe)

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: teal;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

a::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 0.1rem;
  
  transform: rotate(0.5deg);
  background-color: #20c997; /* teal */
  opacity: 0.3;
  transition: height 0.3s;
}

a:hover::after {
  height: 0.5rem;
}
```

Comment: absolute positionning via top:0/top:100% for the transition maybe ?

Comment: I think I found an answer which works but NOT perfect. (It's late now but I just couldn't sleep on it, so I kept trying XD). Here is version 2 of the code: [link](https://codepen.io/minglelingo/pen/rNmLjYz). The problem is that the underline SHUDDERS when making transition if you take a close look,.

Comment: Thank @G-Cyrillus, I can't see it changes... I might put them in the wrong place? I just happen to find out that rotating 181 deg instead of 1deg made the shuddering moderate than before. maybe it made the underline "swiping bottom-up" instead of "standing up"? lol [new code here](https://codepen.io/minglelingo/pen/rNmLjYz)

Comment: i do not see much difference and i'm not sure of the expected result. is underline supposed to be seen, is it supposed to grow from the bottom to the top once hovered and back down once mouse leaves it ? swipe, or is it supposed to be moving like a screenshield swiper ? (rotation)

Answer (score 0):

You just need your underline to be `absolute` positioned to the link bottom. Left and right offset should be set to 0 to grow up to the whole link width (or you can just set `width: 100%;`)

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: teal;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

a::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 0.1rem;
  background-color: #20c997; /* teal */
  opacity: 0.3;
  transition: height 0.3s;
}

a:hover::after {
  height: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">A link text with a animated underline</a>
```